# Selenium RC: Xpath of the link is changed when I refresh the page

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, browser-automation

Selenium RC: Xpath of the link is changed when I refresh the page, and when I run the code it shows `"Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element //*[@id='yui-gen79'] not found".`

How do I handle this error?

First:

```
//*[@id='yui-gen79']
```

After

```
//*[@id='yui-gen98']
```

Page code

```
<document>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body id="Share" class="yui-skin-default alfresco-share js">
<div/>
<div id="overlay" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 90; width: 100%;">
<div id="lightbox" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 100;">
<span class="yui-resize-status"/>
<span class="yui-resize-status"/>
<span class="yui-resize-status"/>
<span class="yui-resize-status"/>
<div id="page_x002e_component-2-2_x002e_user_x007e_sf-er-ro_x007e_dashboard_x0023_default-metadataTooltip" class="yui-module yui-overlay yui-tt yui-overlay-hidden" style="z-index: 2; visibility: hidden;">
<div id="page_x002e_component-2-2_x002e_user_x007e_sf-er-ro_x007e_dashboard_x0023_default-previewTooltip" class="yui-module yui-overlay yui-tt yui-overlay-hidden" style="z-index: 2; width: 108px; visibility: hidden;">
<iframe id="_yuiResizeMonitor" title="Text Resize Monitor" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; background-color: transparent; border-width: 0px; width: 2em; height: 2em; left: 0px; top: -33px;"/>
<div class="sticky-wrapper">
<div id="doc3">
<div id="alf-hd">
<div id="alf-full-width">
<div id="bd">
<div class="yui-gd grid columnSize2">
<div class="yui-u first column1">
<div id="page_x002e_component-1-1_x002e_user_x007e_sf-er-ro_x007e_dashboard">
<div id="page_x002e_component-1-1_x002e_user_x007e_sf-er-ro_x007e_dashboard_x0023_default">
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ (function() {    new Alfresco.dashlet.MySites("page_x002e_component-1-1_x002e_user_x007e_sf-er-ro_x007e_dashboard_x0023_default").setOptions(    {       imapEnabled: false,       listSize: 100    }).setMessages({"empty.title": "Quickly access your sites", "filter.favSites": "My Favorites", "filter.all": "All", "empty.description": "A site is a project area where you can share and discuss content with other site members.", "dashlet.help": "<p>Sites are project areas where you collaborate with others, sharing content and working on it together. This dashlet lists the sites you belong to. You can filter this list to show only your favorite sites.<\/p><p>From here you can:<ul><li>Navigate to a site<\/li><li>Create a new site<\/li><li>Delete a site if you are the site manager<\/li><li>Mark a site as a favorite so that it shows in the Sites menu for easy access<\/li><\/ul><\/p>", "link.deleteSite": "Delete", "link.createSite": "Create Site", "header": "My Sites", "empty.description.sample-site": "We've included a sample site for you. Use this to explore the features in Alfresco Team."});    new Alfresco.widget.DashletResizer("page_x002e_component-1-1_x002e_user_x007e_sf-er-ro_x007e_dashboard_x0023_default", "page.component-1-1.user~sf-er-ro~dashboard#default");    new Alfresco.widget.DashletTitleBarActions("page_x002e_component-1-1_x002e_user_x007e_sf-er-ro_x007e_dashboard_x0023_default").setOptions(    {       actions:       [          {             cssClass: "help",             bubbleOnClick:             {                message: "<p\>Sites are project areas where you collaborate with others, sharing content and working on it together. This dashlet lists the sites you belong to. You can filter this list to show only your favorite sites.</p\><p\>From here you can:<ul\><li\>Navigate to a site</li\><li\>Create a new site</li\><li\>Delete a site if you are the site manager</li\><li\>Mark a site as a favorite so that it shows in the Sites menu for easy access</li\></ul\></p\>"             },             tooltip: "Display help for this dashlet"          }       ]    }); })(); //]]></script>
<div id="yui-gen18" class="dashlet my-sites resizable yui-resize">
<div class="title">My Sites</div>
<div class="toolbar flat-button">
<div class="titleBarActions" style="opacity: 1;">
<div id="page_x002e_component-1-1_x002e_user_x007e_sf-er-ro_x007e_dashboard_x0023_default-sites" class="body scrollableList yui-dt">
<div class="yui-dt-mask" style="display: none;"/>
<table id="yuievtautoid-0" summary="">
<colgroup>
<thead>
<tbody class="yui-dt-message" style="display: none;">
<tbody class="yui-dt-data" tabindex="0" style="">
<tr id="yui-rec72" class="yui-dt-rec yui-dt-first yui-dt-last yui-dt-even yui-dt-highlighted" style="">
<td id="yui-gen106" class="yui-dt12-col-icon yui-dt-col-icon yui-dt-first" headers="yui-dt12-th-icon " style="width: 52px;">
<td id="yui-gen88" class="yui-dt12-col-detail yui-dt-col-detail" headers="yui-dt12-th-detail ">
<div id="yui-gen87" class="yui-dt-liner">
<h3 id="yui-gen92" class="site-title">
<a id="yui-gen98" class="theme-color-1" href="/qa/share/page/site/pfsa/dashboard">pfsa</a>
</h3>
<div id="yui-gen89" class="detail">
<div id="yui-gen86" class="detail detail-social">
</div>
</td>
<td class="yui-dt12-col-actions yui-dt-col-actions yui-dt-last" headers="yui-dt12-th-actions " style="width: 24px;">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="yui-gen56" class="yui-resize-handle yui-resize-handle-b">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="page_x002e_component-1-2_x002e_user_x007e_sf-er-ro_x007e_dashboard">
<div id="unbound-region-component-1-3"/>
<div id="unbound-region-component-1-4"/>
<div id="unbound-region-component-1-5"/>
</div>
<div class="yui-u column2">
</div>
</div>
<div id="alf-id6" class="yui-module yui-overlay" style="z-index: 2; width: 30em; left: 20px; top: 10px;">
<div id="alf-id7" class="yui-module yui-overlay" style="z-index: 2; width: 30em; left: 20px; top: 221px;">
<div id="alf-id8" class="yui-module yui-overlay" style="z-index: 2; width: 30em; left: 436px; top: 10px;">
<div id="alf-id9" class="yui-module yui-overlay" style="z-index: 2; width: 30em; left: 436px; top: 205px;">
</div>
<div class="sticky-push"/>
</div>
<div class="sticky-footer">
<div id="alfresco-yuiloader"/>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[       Alfresco.util.YUILoaderHelper.loadComponents(true);       if (Alfresco.constants.PORTLET)       {          YUIDom.addClass(document.body, "yui-skin-default alfresco-share");       }    //]]></script>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dynamically generated element ids, sometimes I find that you can use `contains` along with a longer xpath locator to match the element. In the sample code provided it looks like only a single anchor element has an id attribute that contains the text "yui-gen" so I would suggest trying

```
//a[contains(@id, 'yui-gen')]
```

Comment: or //a[starts-with(@id, 'yui-gen')] to be more precise.

Comment: In case you have several IDs that starts with 'yui-gen' - which it seems that you could have - try playing around with combinations like this: `//div[starts-with(@id, 'ext-comp-') and ends-with(@id, '32')]//span[contains(text(), 'RAID')]` [also, take a look at W3C's spec](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp).

Comment: Under best practices IDs should be unique, if there are several elements on the page that have the same ID attribute that sounds like an issue that needs to be brought up with the front end developer.